# what should be the approach for linked only answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

This answer of mine got deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32760620/1529129

To start with it was a link only answer pointing to [this blog](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive)

every part of the blog was essential to answer the question as blog post was addressing the specific problem asked in the question.

then I got few downvotes and advice from someone to improve my answer:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

advice looked logical to me and following the advice I tried including essential parts of the blog and ended up including entire blog as everything from the blog was essential to answer the question.

now I was feeling smart ;)

but my answer got deleted with following advice:

> You just copied the whole blog; the write your own answer, and use
>   external links (with perhaps some quoting here) as support. Copying
>   the whole blog is tantamount to copyright infringement.

even this advice seems logical. now I have 2 question.

1. what should be approach for an answer where all the content from a link is essential?
2. can I get a chance to revert my post to its original link only state and get it undeleted?

to answer why it is important to get that answer undeleted, that answer was the only place where URL of the blog is present, **Entire post including question and other answer are referring deleted answer**.

Also when I try to vote for undelete I get following message:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

Comment: You could have posted the link as a comment to the question. Link-only comments are generally *not* frowned upon.

Comment: If you revert the answer to a link only state, it'll be deleted anyway because... well.... link only?. As Glorfindel is saying, comment is your only way here

Comment: @Patrice while I am in agreement with the logic behind your opinion. it was **THE** answer. hence this question.

Comment: Can you write an answer that summarises the blog in your own words with your own examples. If so you could do that (as a new answer). If you don't have the expertise to do that then move on and accept you can't answer this question.

Comment: @RahulTiwari doesn't change the matter that link-only are BAD. If the blog goes down, your answer is now NOTHING. I understand that sometimes this is what happens, but posting this, even if it's THE answer, doesn't make it good. If the ONLY way to answer the original question is to see this link (I'd be surprised if it was, but let's say it is) then the question was not a good fit for Stack to begin with

Comment: Is it your blog or someone else's? Also, you say in your answer that it was already answered so it should be marked as a dupe

Comment: @codeMagic not mine. if that was the case would have mentioned in it question.

Comment: Ok, just asking because it could have made a difference. If it *was* yours then I don't see why it should be deleted. But that is a moot point now. Anyway, again it should be voted to close (or flag in your case) since you found a dupe

Comment: @codeMagic initially it seemed like it was a duplicate. but there was more to it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll try to follow the advice. however won't it help as long as link works? why everyone is so much concerned about what will happen "if link is down". and how does it makes a difference if link was in answer or comment if it is down?

Comment: @RahulTiwari we worry that the link goes down because stack is meant to be a LONG-TERM repository of knowledge. Once your link goes down, all the information that is relevant here is lost to the next user who tries to look up the question.  That's why link-only answers are not appreciated. Rules for comments are less strict

Comment: We're also trying to be a repository of answers, not a repository of links to answers elsewhere. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @RobertLongson does it mean that between  'solution for indeterminate time' and 'no solution at all' we are choosing 'no solution at all'. Here I am in agreement that quality of answer was bad and I am not opposing any downvotes. but even in that case it would have had helped someone coming across the question if not deleted.

Comment: It would have helped for a while and then hindered as soon as the link broke for the rest of time. Becoming a repository of broken links over time is not a useful end goal.

Comment: @RobertLongson is being a repository is a primary goal?

Comment: What else? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217115/is-the-ultimate-goal-of-stack-exchange-really-to-build-a-knowledge-base-for-goog

Answer (score 1):

First problem was that you wrote too little, basically showing no effort in your answer, anyone can copy paste a link.

Second problems was that by copying the entire blog you did the same thing as the first time, just copy pasted some text.

My advice would be that next time you're in the same situation, summarize the contents of the blog/url/link and explain **why** this link will be useful and possibly answer OP's question. This makes your question have more quality and shows that as an answer giver, you genuinely want to help OP solve their issue.

I think your intentions where in the right place, they just weren't executed the right way. Cheer up OP, **there's always the next question**.